# Get current notebook/user context from JupyterHub notebook server?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, jupyterhub

I'm running JupyterHub 0.8.2 on AWS EKS cluster.

I would like to know if it is possible to retrieve the owner of the current notebook server.

E.g.
Let's assume I navigate to `myjupyterhubhost.com/user/john-doe/notebooks/SampleNotebook.ipynb`

In python, I want to do this:

```
user = get_current_context().get_notebook_user_owner()
print(f"The user who owns this notebook server: {user}")

# Output:
# The user who owns this notebook server: john-doe
```

Is there any such function available in the python environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is very simple, the username is stored in an env variable:

```
import os
username = os.environ['JUPYTERHUB_USER']
```